# Loading *.shp.xml file into shapefile for ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, arcgis-10.1, metadata

I am using DRASTIC model and ArcGIS mapping for my thesis of groundwater assessment. I need to generate maps which includes Net Recharge map.

For that I need to export a landuse map and from the data I gathered, I cannot load its as seen below.

[image: Catalog]

the only files in the folder are the following:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Landuse.shp.xml` is the metadata for a shapefile called 'Landuse'.

It does not contain the data.

You will need to relocate the `Landuse.shp` file if you wish to recover your shapefile.

A shapefile called 'Landuse' needs these files at a ***minimum***:

- Landuse.dbf
- Landuse.shp
- Landuse.shx

For a more complete description of what makes up a shapefile see [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/28109) to [How do I load a .dbf file into QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28105/how-do-i-load-a-dbf-file-into-qgis)