# How can I open a standalone .dbf file in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, dbf

Unlike [the apparently similar question already asked where the .dbf is associated with the .shp](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28105/how-do-i-load-a-dbf-file-into-qgis/28115#28115), my problem is simply opening a .dbf in order to join it with a disconnected shapefile by table join.

My question is quite simple: how can I open a .dbf file in QGIS?

I can't find the right instruction to do it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should just be able to use the "Add vector layer..." menu item to open the DBF file.  It will show up as a table layer in the layers panel, and you can refer to it in the table join settings of another layer.

Comment: so simple I didn't think of it...

Answer (score 0):

press "CTRL+L"->"Browser"->Select .dbf file in tree->Add selected layer(s)->Select added in "Layers" panel (if no already selected)->press "F6". voilà