# Adding non-spatial Oracle table to QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, oracle-dbms

I can connect to Oracle database adding and creating spatial layer.

In the same database there are non-spatial tables but I cannot view any of them when connected to the database.

I need to add these tables to QGIS to perform joins with spatial layer.

How do I add non-spatial Oracle table to QGIS?

Comment: In fact, you don't need the tables in QGIS to join them to the table with SDO_GEOMETRY -- the database would do a `JOIN` way faster than QGIS could. If you create views you won't need to fashion queries in the GIS software.

Comment: thanks. some of these tables need to be joined with shape file, also there is standalone tables with .dbf extensions need to be added to qgis  and I don't know how to add standalone table to qgis regarding its type I found tutorial to add  CSV files only, I used Arcmap previously so may be I'm thinking in some matching point

Comment: Your comment has made this three totally different questions. We have a firm "One question per Question" policy, as stated in the [Tour]. Please focus on one question at a time.

Comment: I searched again finding some helpful posts like this one https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/171399/how-can-i-open-a-standalone-dbf-file-in-qgis and I'm trying to create spatial views via oracle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try checking "Also list tables with no geometry." And then let the scan run.

Comment: I don't know why someone rated this answer not useful. This is exactly how you add non-spatial tables from an Oracle spatial connection to QGIS...